# Acer Aspire One - Floppy

Tags: boot, floppy

If I buy an external USB floppy disk drive will my laptop be able to boot from it?
I believe the model is AOA150, it has ZG5 written as model on the bottom also.

Comment: If your bios supports booting from a USB device, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just dug out my AOA150-Ab and a USB floppy disk drive and booted OK to MSDOS 6.22. Ahh, I feel nostalgic!

Comment: There you go. Give this person the check mark for being able to actually test it :)

Comment: Yep, one of the first generation ones. It normally runs Fedora Linux but it has just had a trip back in time!

Comment: Haha, always nice when that happens!

Comment: Just don't ask me to dig out Win95 on its 13 floppies and install that! (Edit: I have just found a comment that Vista would require 1721 HD floppies!)

Comment: Awesome, I'm envying you at the moment :D Thanks for checking out.